# MongoDB GroupBy with multiple ids

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I'm facing some issue while getting records from MongoDB using aggregate query.

I have a collection like below

```
{"_id" : 1,"country" : "us","source" : "ARIN","status" : "NEW","createdDate" : ISODate("2016-05-03T08:52:32.434Z")},
{"_id" : 2,"country" : "us","source" : "ARIN","status" : "NEW","createdDate" : ISODate("2016-05-03T09:52:32.434Z")},
{"_id" : 3,"country" : "cn","source" : "APNIC","status" : "NEW","createdDate" : ISODate("2016-05-03T10:52:32.434Z")},
{"_id" : 4,"country" : "eu","source" : "RIPE","status" : "NEW","createdDate" : ISODate("2016-05-03T10:52:32.434Z")},
{...}
```

I used below query

> db.collecton.aggregate(   [       {"$group" : {
>             _id:{source:"$source",status:"$status"},            count:{$sum:1}          }
>         }   ] )

I'm getting a result like below

```
{ "_id" : { "source" : "RIPE", "status" : "NEW" }, "count" : 29260 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "RIPE", "status" : "ERROR" }, "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "LACNIC", "status" : "NEW" }, "count" : 5889 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "KRNIC", "status" : "NEW" }, "count" : 105 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "APNIC", "status" : "NEW" }, "count" : 6644 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "AFRINIC", "status" : "NEW" }, "count" : 1326 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "JPNIC", "status" : "NEW" }, "count" : 167 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "ARIN", "status" : "NEW" }, "count" : 25420 }
{ "_id" : { "source" : "ARIN", "status" : "DONE" }, "count" : 9 }
```

But, My expected result should be like this

```
[
    {
        "source" : "RIPE"
        "status" : {
            "NEW": 29260,
            "ERROR": 10
        }
    },
    {

        "source" : "LACNIC"
        "status" : {
            "NEW": 5889
        }
    },
    {

        "source" : "ARIN"
        "status" : {
            "NEW": 25420,
            "DONE": 9
        }
    },
    {...}
]
```

OR

```
[
    {
        "source" : "RIPE"
        "status" : [
            {"status" : "NEW", "count": 29260},
            {"status" : "ERROR" , "count" : 10}
        ]
    },
    {
        "source" : "LACNIC"
        "status" : [
            {"status" : "NEW", "count": 5889}
        ]
    },
    {
        "source" : "ARIN"
        "status" : [
            {"status" : "NEW", "count": 25420},
            {"status" : "DONE" , "count" : 9}
        ]
    },
    {...}
]
```

please help me out of this, thank you

Comment: Provided link is exactly same, Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584092/count-no-of-instances-of-string-in-a-field-across-documents-grouped-on-another-f/60584162#60584162 ? Anyway I've done it, Check this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/n91n02bzgmF

Comment: Ya it is working. thank you @whoami